# print readable message for tiny int value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a column `PAID tinyint(1)`. Now I want to display this value 0/1 as UNPAID/PAID in view page table. How should I do this?

Also if the PAID column data is PAID then color it as green and if UNPAID then color it as BLUE. How can I do this?

controller code block to fetch data

```
function fetchData() {
    $ordered_books = OrderedBook::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
    return compact('ordered_books');
}
```

view page table code block

```
<table id="showBooksIn" class="table table-bordered gridview">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>BOOK ID</th>
            <th>BILLED DATE</th>
            <th>BILLED NUMBER</th>
            <th>QUANTITY</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>PAID</th>
            <th>REMARKS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($ordered_books as $data)
        <tr>
            <td> {{$data['BookID']}} </td>
            <td> {{$data['BilledDate']}} </td>
            <td> {{$data['BilledNum']}} </td>
            <td> {{$data['Qunatity']}} </td>
            <td> {{$data['Price']}} </td>
            <td> {{$data->bill_paid}} </td>
            <td> {{$data['Remarks']}} </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As suggested I edited my model class

```
class OrderedBook extends Model
{
    //
    protected $appends = ['bill_paid'];

    public function getBillPaidAttribute(){
        if($this->BillPaid == 0){
           return 'UNPAID';
        }else {
          return 'PAID'; 
        }
      }
}
```

Now getting error as ::  `ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined property: App\OrderedBook::$BillPaid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if conditions in your blade template and apply css for coloring.

```
@foreach($ordered_books as $data)
 <tr>
     <td> {{$data['BookID']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['BilledDate']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['BilledNum']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['Qunatity']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['Price']}} </td>

     @if($data['BillPaid'] === 0)
        <td style='color:blue;'> UNPAID </td>
     @else
        <td style='color:green;'> PAID </td>
     @endif

     <td> {{$data['Remarks']}} </td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

make Eloquent: Mutators in OrderBook

```
protected $appends = ['bill_status']

public function getBillStatusAttribute(){
  if($this->BillPaid == 0){
     return 'unpaid';
  }else {
    return 'paid'; 
  }
}
```

in view

```
 $orderBook->bill_status
```

Comment: how to access it in view page. Please help.

Comment: just write `$orderBook->bill_paid` in your view

Comment: how to access as table data,`<td> {{$data['BillPaid']}} </td>`

Comment: write this  `protected $appends =['bill_paid']` after your fillable attributes

Comment: I've edited my code as you suggested still getting error. Please see the question I've edited my code getting error as  `ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined property: App\OrderedBook::$BillPaid`

Comment: try to change this as written in my answer

Comment: still getting the same error `Undefined property: App\OrderedBook::$BillPaid`